# Showing no error but still not loading a view after RedirectToAction

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an application in asp.net mvc

I have a controller named LoginController which has two action method

1. Index
2. loginCheck(Username, Password)

Both return ActionResult

Index action return view which has a login form.

//Code

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return view();
    }
}
```

loginCheck action method is called using ajax call when a user click login button on login form.

WithIn loginCheck I'm checking username and password if it is correct I'm creating a session using
`Session["User"] = Username` And `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Configuration");`

//Here is code

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult loginCheck(string UserName, string Password)
    {

        Getting user Id and password

        Checking

        If(correct)
        Then
            Session["User"] = Username;

            return RefirectToAction("Index", "Cobfiguration");
        Else
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

After above line the control goes to `Index` action method of Configuration controller.

It checks session if exist then do stuff and return view of configuration action method Index with data in an object of Configuration model class, and if session doesnot exist then just return login index action which basically loads login form.

```
if (Session["User"] != null)
{
      //do stuff
       return view(modelObject);
}
else
{
      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
}
```

So the problem is `controller` is transferring to index method of configuration controller, code is executing everything and even `return view(modelObject);` but the view of configuration index is not showing. I don't understand why.

Anything anyone can tell?

Comment: Can you try return view("Index", modelObject)

Comment: Well that's the thing I don't have view for every action method, like I have an add functionality and after success index actionmethod is called which loads view (basically after success index view is loaded and display data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using AJAX to call the method, the whole process happens without reloading the page. Everything is executing as expected, but the page is not reloading. You need to either handle the redirect in the callback of your AJAX call, or just send the POST request synchronously.